# Content overflow outside the div

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I got a problem on Firefox (not present on Chrome nor on Safari). The content I display goes outside of the div like this :

[image: Firefox]

This is what I got on Chrome : It perfectly fit the parents div [image: Chrome]

This is the html :

```
<div style="vertical-align:top; display:inline;" class="buttons">
  <button id="b1">RDC Bas</button>
  <button id="b2" >RDC Haut</button>
</div>
<div id="plan-boutiques" class="boxes">
  <div id="first">
    <img src="img/rdc_bas.png" alt="">
    <a href="" id="carrefour"><p>7</p></a>
    <!-- a link continues -->
  </div>

  <div id="sec" style="display: none;">
    <img src="img/rdc_haut.png" alt="">
    <a href="" id="recre"><p>8</p></a>
    <!-- a link continues -->
  </div>

</div>
```

The CSS :

```
#plan-boutiques a {
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 100px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
    height: 26px;
    width: 26px;
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 25px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    background-position: 0 -27px;
}

#plan-boutiques {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
#plan-boutiques > img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 676px;
    max-height: 507px;
}

a#carrefour {
    margin-left: 56.92%;
    margin-top: -32.02%;
}
a#recre {
    margin-left: 23.92%;
    margin-top: -50.02%;
}
.boxes, .buttons{
    float: left;
}   
#b1, #b2 {
    height: auto;
    width: 336px;
    max-height: 30px;
}
```

As it is an article in Joomla I don't want to modify the parent div, I just want to modify what I built !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change:

```
#plan-boutiques > img { ... }
```

To:

```
#plan-boutiques img { ... }
```

As image is not a direct child of `#plan-boutiques`.

Comment: Thanks ! Real quick :)